# Using sed/awk to modify huge JSON file

Tags: json, regex, awk, sed

I have a JSON file like this, i want to use sed/awk to replace certain keys and add new keys like, I cannot use json parsers like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) as this requires installation procedure and the product environment is limited.

Input:

```
[{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "23456734",
    "nestedKey1": {
        "234567890": {
            "key2": "value3",
            "key4": "value4"
        }
    }
}]
```

Output:

```
[{
    "key2": "value1:23456734",
    "nestedKey1": {
        "CONSTANT:234567890": {
            "key4": "value4"
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Frankly, you should just suck it up and get jq on there. The manipulation you're doing here isn't trivial but is in jq.  The same can't be said using sed/awk.

Comment: `jq` is a great tool for this, but if you really can't install it, what else is available in the environment? `sed` and `awk` are going to have a really hard time with this, but Perl or Python would do.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the target environment is a production environment that is restricted, it has RHEL6 with basic GNU utils

Comment: what happened to key2 in the nested part?

Comment: what do you do if you have 3 keys instead of 2?

Comment: The rest of the keys are untouched, I have put a simplified version, the data  is in such a way that only the above mentioned keys are modified, rest of the them are untouched. Even if it has 3 or more keys only the above mentioned keys(in example) will be modified

Comment: Installing `jq` shouldn't be a big deal and it is definitely the way to go. Parsing a JSON with `awk` and `sed` can make things even worse.

Comment: Use a proper tool. Regex are not a proper tool for that kind of work. Any programming language installed on the machine in question will most probably have a JSON parser. Use a programming language for manipulating JSON.

Comment: Besides [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) there's also [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk) as a better alternative to awk for handling json files. But I would at least verify if that RHEL6 server has a higher  programming language installed like Perl or Python or Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed is not the right tool for that.

That said, the following command will work with your sample file (use it **at your own risk** in your production environment) :

```
sed '
/ *"key1"/ {
  N
  s/ *"key1": "\([^"]*\)",\n\( *"key2": \)"\([0-9]*\)"/\2"\1:\3"/
}
/"nestedKey1": {/ {
  N
  s/"\([0-9]*"\)/ "CONSTANT:\1/
  n
  /key2/d
}
' file
```